# Read tgz w/out unpacking it onto computer or Unpack as temp & delete when program closes?

Tags: java, desktop

Hey guys I'm currently using jarchivelib which can be found [Here](http://rauschig.org/jarchivelib/examples.html) I'm stuck on figuring out a way to read the file without having to use the unpack method because it makes a file of the unpacked version. EX:

```
File archive = new File("/home/jack/archive.zip");
```

`File destination = new File("/home/jack/archive");`

`Archiver archiver = ArchiverFactory.createArchiver(ArchiveFormat.ZIP);`
`archiver.extract(archive, destination);`

I want to make it so i don't have to unpack it to read the files... If there is no way to do that I'm guessing in my method for Jframe.setDefualtCloseOpperation i'll have to make a custom one so it deletes the files? or is there a better way for handling temp files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is to extract the file, why not use Java's built in zip to [extract the file](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-unzip-the-contents-of-a-zip-file.html) or if it is password protected you can use [Zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/). These libraries support streams, so that you can extract the contents of the file without writing it a FileStream

Comment: Quick question. How do I use the extractfilewithinputstream method?
at the top it contains:
`ZipFile zipFile=newZipFile("C:\\ZipTest\\ExtractAllFilesWithInputStreams.zip");`
`String destinationPath = "c:\\ZipTest";`
What do i put int these? my current zip file i just made with the packer? or?

Answer (score 0):

As of version 0.4.0, the [jarchivelib](http://rauschig.org/jarchivelib) `Archiver` API supports streaming an archive rather than extracting it directly onto the filesystem.

```
ArchiveStream stream = archiver.stream(archive);
ArchiveEntry entry;

while((entry = stream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    // access each archive entry individually using the stream
    // or extract it using entry.extract(destination)
    // or fetch meta-data using entry.getName(), entry.isDirectory(), ...
}
stream.close();
```

when the stream is pointing to an entry after calling `getNextEntry`, you can use the `stream.read` methods just as you would reading an individual entry.